# Node.js and express : Routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have some trouble using the router from Express.
I want to set up my routes with several files.
I get my routes folder with 2 files: routes.js and inscription.js

I do the following

```
var inscription = require('./routes/inscription.js');
var routes = require('./routes/routes.js');
```

Then

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/inscription', inscription);
```

But only the routes from routes.js work...

This is the content of routes.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});

//Homepage
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.status(200);
    res.render('home.ejs');
});

//Connexion
router.post('/connexion', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    //Some content
});
module.exports = router;
```

And this is the content of inscription.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var hash = require('password-hash');
var db = require('../models/users.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});

router.get('/inscription', function(req, res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.status(200);
    res.render('inscription.ejs');
});
router.post('/adduser', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    var passwordHashed = hash.generate(req.body.inputPassword);
    var newUser = {
        nom      : req.body.inputName,
        email     : req.body.inputEmail,
        password : passwordHashed
    };
    db.addUser(newUser);
    res.redirect('/');
});
router.post('/checkname', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    var user = {
        nom      : req.body.inputName
    };
    db.checkName(user, function(length){
        res.send(length);
    });
});
router.post('/checkemail', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    var user = {
        email      : req.body.inputEmail
    };
    db.checkEmail(user, function(length){
        res.send(length);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

The content of inscription.js works when it is pasted in the routes.js file ...
So I guess it is how I import the file that is not working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This route `router.get('/inscription', ...)` in your inscription router is configured for the route `/inscription/inscription` which is likely not what you intended.  This is because you've specified it in two places:

```
app.use('/inscription', inscription);
router.get('/inscription', ...)
```

So, the whole router is on `/inscription` from the `app.use('/inscription', inscription)`.  That means that any route the router itself defines will be **added** to that path.

It isn't exactly clear from your question exactly what you intend for the URLs to be.  But, if you just want the above `router.get()` to work for a `/inscription` URL, then change:

```
router.get('/inscription', ...)
```

to:

```
router.get('/', ...)
```

When you use `app.use('/inscription', inscription);`, every single route in that router will be prefixed with `/inscription`.  So, this route:

```
router.post('/adduser', ...)
```

will be mounted at:

```
/inscription/adduser
```

---

Or, if you want all the inscription routes to be at the top level too, then change:

```
app.use('/inscription', inscription);
```

to this:

```
app.use('/', inscription);
```

So that nothing is added to the path beyond what the router itself defines.

Comment: Oh I see! I didn’t know that it works that way! Thanks for your very clear explanation! It is possible to avoid including route in the app.js file ... I mean to use directly app.use() in the routes.js and only do a require at the top of the app.js file?

Comment: @Jeremy - Usually, it works best to export the router from routes.js and then just do `app.use(require('./routes.js'))` in app.js.  routes.js does not know the right `app` object so the only way it can do things itself is if you pass it the `app` object by exporting a function and then calling that function from app.js and passing the `app` object.  That is not typically what people do because the above suggestion is simpler.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot for your helpful comments!